# Selenium node/chrome docker image and selenium/hub docker image in different host machines

Tags: docker, selenium-grid

I have a situation where i have to use the node/chrome and selenium/hub images in different host machines. However problem is although i am linking them in the ansible role as below:

```
- name: seleniumchromenode container
  docker:
    name: seleniumhubchromenode
    image: "{{ seleniumchromenode_image }}"
    state: "{{ 'started' }}"
    pull: always
    restart_policy: always
    links: seleniumhub:hub
```

It doesnt get linked , or in other words the hub is not discovering the node. Please let me know if linking works only when the hub and node are within the same host machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is what finally worked for me. Note that the SE_OPTS is necessary for the node to be able to link successfully to the hub that is on a different host.

```
- name: seleniumchromenode container
  docker_container:
    name: seleniumhubchromenode
    image: "{{ seleniumchromenode_image }}"
    state: "{{ 'started' }}"
    pull: true
    restart_policy: always
    exposed_ports:
      - "{{seleniumnode_port}}"
    published_ports:
      - "{{seleniumnode_port}}:{{seleniumnode_port}}"
    env:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: "{{seleniumhub_host}}"
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: "{{seleniumhub_port}}"
      SE_OPTS: "-host {{seleniumnode_host}} -port {{seleniumnode_port}}"
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: "5"
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: "5"
```

Answer (score 3):

Links don't work across machines. You can either specify the IP address/hostname and let it connect through that, or you can use Docker Swarm Mode to deploy your containers - that lets you do something very close to linking (it sets up a mesh network across the swarm nodes, so services can find each other).

Simplest: just pass the hostname in Ansible.

Comment: Thanks, i have managed to solve this as per your suggestion posting the code here if it will help anyone: